# OpenCL: what is the purpose and effective uses of private memory?

Tags: c, memory, opencl

I understand local memory (I think): by copying portions from global to local you can allow a workgroup quicker access to the data in on-chip SRAM.

What use is private memory then? I've read that it's off-chip for one, e.g. a reserved part of global mem. So it won't be faster than local. And it's reserved for each work-item I believe (or in hardware, a SIMD lane).

Feel free to give an example that might help me understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private memory have two usages :

- **fast storage** (kind of **registers**/ **L1 cache**) if it's small enough, faster than local memory
- **private storage** in **global memory** for each work-item if all the private data cannot fit neither into registers nor into local memory

Comment: So you're saying private memory *could* be on-chip if the compiler detects that it's small enough? I was not aware of this possibility. If what you say is true, then I guess private mem could be good to store a few constant params that get read often, for example.

Comment: I just read in Computer Architecture by H&P, "Recent GPUs cache this private memory in the L1 and L2 caches to aid register spilling and speed up function calls." Which agrees with your answer (the sentence before they mention off-chip DRAM for private mem). The question then becomes: how to tell which device does what with private memory? I'm sure one could contact the vendors, but ideally you'd want to determine this dynamically at runtime.

Comment: One more comment: I just find it weird that private memory can either be the fastest or the slowest of memories =)

Comment: The way private and constant data are managed is indeed device specific. It will depend on the device capability to store more or less data in registers or cache L1/L2 or other dedicated memory area. Now it's up to you to decide if the gains obtained by optimizing your kernel for a perfect use of the device capabilities is worth the pain. If you are working with a huge uniform GPU cluster you have the time to understand the unique architecture and you can write your kernels once.

Comment: But if you are distributing your kernel and do not have any control over the final hardware you'll have to find the happy medium by optimizing only for a subset of supported GPUs.